# How to only update a single field in DynamoDB using AWS Go SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-dynamodb

hope someone can shed some light on this issue I've been trying to wrap my head around.

I've got this table in Dynamo, let's call it `people` and in this table, I've got the attributes of `id` as our partition key, `name`, `lastName`, and `status`.
I'd like to be able to just update either a single attribute or all of them save for the ID.
Now, this is how I've gone about it. I've created the following struct:

```
type PersonUpdate struct {
    FirstName     string `json:"firstName,omitempty"`
    LastName      string `json:"lastName,omitempty"`
    Status        string `json:"status,omitempty"`
}
```

And the request coming from the server would be to just update the person's last name, so our request body would look as follows:

```
{
    "lastName": "bob"
}
```

After we bind our request to our struct the object that would be sent to dynamo looks as as such:

```
{
    "firstName": "",
    "lastName": "bob",
    "status": "",
}
```

Now when it's time to write to dynamo as you can see, only one attribute should be updated while the rest which are empty/null should be ignored.

The code written to perform this action can be condensed to the following actions:

```
    // Marshal our object
    _, err := dynamodbattribute.MarshalMap(person)
    if err != nil{
        fmt.Println("some error marshaling")
    }
    // Create our update input
    input := &dynamodb.UpdateItemInput{
        key: map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue{
            "id":{
                S: aws.String("1234"),
            },
        },
        TableName: aws.String("people"),
        ExpressionAttributeValues: map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue{
            ":fn": {
                S: aws.String(person.FirstName),
            },
            ":ln":{
                S: aws.String(person.LastName),
            },
            ":st":{
                S: aws.String(person.Status),
            },
        },
        UpdateExpression: aws.String("set firstName = :fn, lastName = :ln, status = :st"),
        ReturnValues: aws.String("UPDATED_NEW"),
    }
    // Send update request to Dynamo
    _, err := service.UpdateItem(input)
```

Now, the update goes through with no issues, the problem is that the values for `firstName` and `status` which are null are getting passed as well. I've tried to go through their documentation but left a bit more confused. I know for a fact the Java SDK allows you to pass a flag called `UPDATE_SKIP_NULL_ATTRIBUTES` which allows you to skip those empty values and only update those which have data. I don't know what would be the equivalent in Go, any assistance/guidance would be great.

Update:

Tried to use the following model:

```
type UserModel struct {
    FirstName string `json:"firstName,omitempty" dynamodbav:"firstName,omitempty"`
    LastName  string `json:"lastName,omitempty" dynamodbav:"lastName,omitempty"`
}
```

following the suggestion given by @jarmod and @fedonev. Logically and using the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/dynamodb/dynamodbattribute/#Marshal) it makes sense why this should work, unfortunately, it didn't

Decided to switch the SDK from V1 to V2 and see if maybe updating it would help, again though I'm in the same hole. This is what my update function looks like.

```
    update :=expression.Set(expression.Name("firstName"),expression.Value(user.FirstName))
    update.Set(expression.Name("lastName"), expression.Value(user.LastName))

    expr, err := expression.NewBuilder().WithUpdate(update).Build()

    if err != nil {
        "log error here..."
    }

    _, err = svc.UpdateItem(context.TODO(), &dynamodb.UpdateItemInput{
        TableName:                 aws.String("people"),
        Key:                       map[string]types.AttributeValue{"id": id},
        ExpressionAttributeNames:  expr.Names(),
        ExpressionAttributeValues: expr.Values(),
        UpdateExpression:          expr.Update(),
        ReturnValues:              types.ReturnValueUpdatedNew,
    })

    if err != nil {
        "log error here..."

    }
```

I ended up solving my problem by writing a query-and-create function, which pretty much queries by the ID that we'd like to update takes in the JSON payload, and make a diff of the query against what we need to update and any empty fields get replaced by the query results. So far it solves my problem but I still would like to know how to go about doing an update using its intended function.

Comment: Typically, you would only send the attributes that you want updated. I see mention of an `omitempty` capability in the Go SDK [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/dynamodb/dynamodbattribute/) but am not familiar with this SDK, but worth investigating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @jarmod's comment says, apply the `dynamodbav:",omitempty"` tag to [skip zero-value fields](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/dynamodb/dynamodbattribute/#Marshal) when marshaling the struct:

```golang
type PersonUpdate struct {
    FirstName     string `json:"firstName,omitempty" dynamodbav:",omitempty"`
    LastName      string `json:"lastName,omitempty" dynamodbav:",omitempty"`
    Status        string `json:"status,omitempty" dynamodbav:",omitempty"`
}
```

[Edit: add usage] `MarshalMap` will now ignore zero-value fields, respecting the tags.  Iterate over the map to construct the update expression:

```golang
av, _ := attributevalue.MarshalMap(person)

update := expression.UpdateBuilder{}

for k, v := range av {
        update = update.Set(expression.Name(k), expression.Value(v))
}
```

Build the expression and pass its outputs to `UpdateItem`, as in the OP.

Comment: Thanks for your help, gave it a spin unfortunately the behavior remains. I've tried to switch to the v2 golang SDK and sadly the examples online are not that good. I did try the following, your feedback would be appreciated. I'll update my question with the new attemp.

Comment: @Caliman - In order to take advantage of the `omitempty` tags, you must use the `map[string]types.AttributeValue` returned by `MarshalMap` to build your update expression.  See my updated answer for usage.

Comment: You my friend @fedonev, just gave me an amazing belated Christmas gift :). I understand this now, thank you again. It worked as expected, thanks for your patience and wisdom. 