# ExpressionAttributeValues issue when updating single field in AWS DynamoDB via Go SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-dynamodb

Following the setup described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74806198/how-to-only-update-a-single-field-in-dynamodb-using-aws-go-sdk), I get the following error:

```
cannot use expr.Values() (value of type map[string]*"github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/dynamodb".AttributeValue) as map[string]"github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/dynamodb/types".AttributeValue value in struct literal
```

when running the following code:

```
    ivm, err := attributevalue.MarshalMap(person)

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    update := expression.UpdateBuilder{}

    for k, v := range ivm {
        update = update.Set(expression.Name(k), expression.Value(v))
    }
    expr, err := expression.NewBuilder().WithUpdate(update).Build()

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    input := &dynamodb.UpdateItemInput{
        TableName:                 aws.String(table),
        Key:                       map[string]types.AttributeValue{"PK": &types.AttributeValueMemberS{Value: pk}, "SK": &types.AttributeValueMemberS{Value: sk}},
        ExpressionAttributeNames:  convertMapStringPtrToMapString(expr.Names()),
        ExpressionAttributeValues: expr.Values(),
        UpdateExpression:          expr.Update(),
        ReturnValues:              types.ReturnValueAllNew,
    }
```

**person** is build out when using the request info with the PersonUpdate struct that looks as follows where secondName can be empty:

```
type PersonUpdate struct {
    PK                   string `json:"-" dynamodbav:"PK"`
    SK                   string `json:"-" dynamodbav:"SK"`
    FirstName            string `json:"firstName" dynamodbav:"FirstName"`
    SecondName           string `json:"secondName,omitempty" dynamodbav:",omitempty"`
}
```

Looks like this is a mismatch between the MarshalMap return value type and what ExpressionAttributeValues expects. Not sure how to resolve this besides using reflection to build out the update expression. This however seems heavy handed given the previous post where this seems to have worked without reflection. Any guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: issue was resolved by ensuring that I am importing the v2 AWS Go SDK "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/feature/dynamodb/expression" vs "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/dynamodb/expression"